Need inputs on logging Machine Learning models and their versions in logs for my application
So i have a web application that recommends movies based on the subject and question that the user puts in , it also uses NLP and ML models like Named Entity Recognition(NER) model to extract keywords and BERT model as well. I am currently just logging the login data into one of my database tables in sql . Now I also want to log the ML model and their version into the table as well .
I have a few capture points in my mind i.e when would this data be captured . One is when the user logs in and second is when the user adds the movie to the list . I thought of implementing this so that I can improve the accuracy of ML models and track performance. It will also help me to detect any kind of discrepancy if any irrelevant recommendation is made .
the plan is to just log which model was triggered when the recommendations are made and the version of it . basically i also show the keywords that are matching with the recommended movies , so probably also from which models those keywords are coming from and the version
I am just confused as to how i would go about implementing this , and wanted some inputs if anyone has worked on such a similar thing before. would be helpful.
